# lumen with mongodb :getting error : Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, lumen

I am working with lumen and mongodb

I want to get (total unread) and total messages count based on folder

my mongodb query is like below,

```
$totalEmails = DB::connection('mongodb')
        ->select("sum(if(is_read==0,1,0)) as unread", "count(message_id) as total", "folder_id")
        ->collection('email_message')
        ->where('email_account_id', (int)$request->email_account_id)
        ->where('status', "Active")
        ->groupBy("folder_id")
        ->get();
```

it gives me error as below,

```
FatalErrorException in Connection.php line 333:
Call to a member function prepare() on null
```

please help me to resolve this issue.thank you.

I have resolve that error by change my query as below,

```
$totalEmails = DB::connection('mongodb')            
            ->collection('email_message')
            ->select("sum(if(is_read==0,1,0)) as unread", "count(message_id) as total", "folder_id")
            ->where('email_account_id', (int)$request->email_account_id)
            ->where('status', "Active")
            ->groupBy("folder_id")
            ->get();
```

but it not gives me expected result,

it give me result as below,

```
[_id] => Array
            (
                [folder_id] => 5bee461e19f043020c001844
            )

    [folder_id] => 5bee461e19f043020c001844
    [sum(if(is_read==0,1,0)) as unread] => 
    [count(message_id) as total] =>
```

but my expectation is

```
[_id] => Array
            (
                [folder_id] => 5bee461e19f043020c001844
            )

    [folder_id] => 5bee461e19f043020c001844
    [unread] => 2
    [total] => 10
```

can you tell me where is wrong in query???

If I am using below query

```
$totalEmails = DB::connection('mongodb')
    ->selectRaw("sum(if(is_read==0,1,0)) as unread", "count(message_id) as total", "folder_id")
    ->collection('email_message')
    ->where('email_account_id', (int)$request->email_account_id)
    ->where('status', "Active")
    ->groupBy("folder_id")
    ->get();
```

it gives me error like,

```
ErrorException in Builder.php line 245:
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::selectRaw() must be of the type array, string given,
```

If I am using below query,

```
 $totalEmails = DB::connection('mongodb')        
        ->collection('email_message')
        ->selectRaw("sum(if(is_read==0,1,0)) as unread,count(message_id) as total,folder_id")
        ->where('email_account_id', (int)$request->email_account_id)
        ->where('status', "Active")
        ->groupBy("folder_id")
        ->get();
```

it gives me result like,

```
[_id] => Array
                (
                    [folder_id] => 5bee461e19f043020c001844
                )

            [folder_id] => 5bee461e19f043020c001844
            [sum(if(is_read==0,1,0)) as unread,count(message_id) as total,folder_id] =>
```

please help me to get my expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a complex query to execute and very hard to produce with the laravel methods as far as I know, so I would recommend a raw query by using `$aggregate` like the following example:

```
$totalEmails = DB::connection("mongodb")
    ->collection("email_message")
    ->raw(function ($collection) {
        return $collection->aggregate(
            [
                [
                    "\$match" => [
                        "email_account_id" => (int)$request->email_account_id,
                        "status" => "active"
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    "\$group" => [
                        "_id" => [
                            "folder_id" => "\$folder_id"
                        ],
                        "unread" => [
                            "\$sum" => [
                                "\$switch" => [
                                    "branches" => [
                                        ["case" => [
                                            "\$eq" => [
                                                "\$is_read", '0,1,0'
                                            ]
                                        ],
                                            "then" => 1
                                        ]
                                    ],
                                    "default" => 0
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        "total" => [
                            "\$sum" => 1
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );
    });

$collectedResult = array();
foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
    $collectResult[] = $v->jsonSerialize();
}

return $collectedResult;
```

I have formatted it to be as readable as possible and I will try to explain every part of the query as well as possible so you know what it does.

By using the `raw` statement we can use the `aggregate()` function which simulates the mongo `$aggregate`.

First we want to filter on `email_account_id` which is done with the `$match` method, note that the `$` is escaped because otherwise php will interpret it as a variable.

After that we need to perform the group by which is done with this part:

```
"_id" => [
      "folder_id" => "\$folder_id"
]
```

This will create the `_id` column with in it an array with the key `folder_id` and will collect all unique values of the DB column 'folder_id' into the value.

Thus this part will produce an array of elements with unique folder_ids, then the unread and total messages will have to be counted for these folders.

The total is simple and is done with the `$sum` operator. The unread part is a bit more complex because this will need to filter on the `is_read` operator. Which is done with a switch statement and a default value of 0 (don't count when condition fails).

The raw query will return a `MongoCursor` so the last part is to collect these results

I hope this helps you and if anything is unclear please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what is causing your issue but you have an error in your code

It should be:

```
$totalEmails = DB::connection('mongodb')
    ->selectRaw("sum(if(is_read==0,1,0)) as unread, count(message_id) as total, folder_id")
    ->collection('email_message')
    ->where('email_account_id', (int)$request->email_account_id)
    ->where('status', "Active")
    ->groupBy("folder_id")
    ->get();
```

The selectRaw is needed to include raw code in the select. Here is the docs for more info

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: I have also try this, but it gives me result as , [_id] => Array
                (
                    [folder_id] => 5bee461e19f043020c001844
                )

            [folder_id] => 5bee461e19f043020c001844
            [sum(if(is_read==0,1,0)) as unread,count(message_id) as total,folder_id] =>

Comment: Change select to selectRaw and make it a single string

Comment: thanks,I have update my question for that , what is happening in this ,please look in to it

Comment: Hi Hetel I would suggest that your issue is now with the raw code as it does not look like it uses mongoDB language but I am not familiar with it.